# С чего начать изучение C++?

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Есть вопрос: с чего начать изучение C++?

Я знаю, что это сложный язык, потому спрашиваю у вас. У каждого языка программирования есть основа, без которой просто никуда. Что вы посоветуете пройти для начала?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: обычно все начинают со школьной программы basic и pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) извините, но Шилдта очень [ругают](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/BadBooksC+C++.html#SchildtAny), да и книги старые очень. Не советую.

2) создатель языка С++ Бьярн Страуструп крайне не советует начинать изучение C++  с языка C

3) личный опыт: лучше хорошая c++ либа, чем хорошая c-либа.

4) что читать: [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines), книга "Скользкие места C++" очень хороша.

5) читать хорошие [блоги](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/blogroll.html) и [сайт](http://isocpp.org) комитета по стандартизации C++

Answer (score 11):

Ох, ну сейчас я накидаю список.

**Язык Си**

Поскольку язык С++ включает в себя язык Си, который намного проще изучить, я бы советовал начинать с него. В частности с Шилдта - ["Полный справочник по Си"](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/main.htm). Это единственная книга, в которой я не встретил просто кучу устаревшей информации с ошибкой в каждом втором примере(привет книге K&R).

Однако, изучение Си не обязательно, хотя я и рекомендую.

**Что же касается самого с++**

1. ***Роберт Лафоре - "Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++"***

   Замечательная книга по С++ для новичков. Написана простым, лаконичным и понятным языком, материал разбирается детально и подробно. Рекомендую как самую первую по С++. Есть примеры для решения. Читать, одно удовольствие. Единственный минус, которыя я отметил - автор сильно и часто перехваливает достоинства языка по тексту книги.
2. ***Герберт Шилдт - Полный справочник по C++***

   Прочитав Лафоре, можно углуюлять в детали языка и посмотреть своеобразный справочник-учебник по С++. Здесь будет сказано все то, чего не было сказано в первой книге.

Далее идет список, который я не читал, но книги из него рекомендуют так же на многих ресурсах как самые лучшие.

- Брюс Эккель, Чак Эллисон - "Философия C++. Введение в стандартный C++."
- Брюс Эккель, Чак Эллисон - "Философия C++. Практическое программирование."
- Стенли Липпман, Жози Лажойе - "Язык программирования C++. Вводный курс"
- Стенли Липпман - "Основы программирования на С++. Том 1"

**Отлично, это был С++, но так же есть его библиотека STL, которой посвящены так же отдельные книги и Boost. А так же разбор продвинутых техник программирования на С++.**

1. Питер Нортон Скотт Мейерс - "Эффективное использование STL"
2. Николай Джосьютис - "C++ Стандартная библиотека. Для профессионалов."
3. П. Плаугер, А. Степанов - "STL. Стандартная библиотека шаблонов C++"

Обязательно ознакомьтесь потом с BOOST, книг к сожалению не знаю.

- Питер Нортон Скотт Мейерс - "Наиболее эффективное использование C++. 35 новых способов улучшить стиль программирования."
- Нортон Скотт Мейерс - "Эффективное использование C++. 50 рекомендаций по улучшению ваших программ и проектов."
- Питер Нортон Скотт Мейерс - "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ."
- Герб Саттер - "Новые сложные задачи на C++"
- Герб Саттер - "Решение сложных задачи на C++"
- Андрей Александреску, Герб Саттер - "Стандарты программирования на С++. 101 правило и рекомендация"
- **Не забудьте прочитать книгу четырех о шаблонах проектирования**.

**Страуструп**

Если Вы прочитали множество приведенных книг и получили достаточно опыта, то самое время переходить к трудам Страуструпа. Книги его написаны академическим языком и читаются достаточно сложно. Некоторые рекомендуют начинать с него, но только от того, что сами с него начинали, когда на рынке больше никакой годной литературы не было. ОДнозначно не берите его первым, но он обязателен для хорошего программиста С++.

**Еще не надоело клепать скучные консольные приложения? Самое время перейти к изучению QT.
Или же изучения программированию под Windows.**

QT

- Макс Шлее "Qt 4.8. Профессиональное программирование на С++"
- Бланшет, Саммерфилд - "Qt4 Программирование GUI на С++"
- Марк Саммерфилд - Qt Профессиональное программирование (High tech) - 2011
- Андрей Боровский - Qt4.7+. Практическое программирование на C++ - 2012

Немного Windows мозгодробилки, но вместо WinAPI можно почитать что-то более высокоуровневое, всякие там MFC, WTL. Да, первые две книги для windows 95, но с тех пор WinAPI вообще не менялся,  книги являются отличным пособием.

- Чарльз Петцольд - "Программирование для Windows 95. Том 1"
- Чарльз Петцольд - "Программирование для Windows 95. Том 2"
- Джеффри Рихтер - "Windows для профессионалов"

Ну в общем-то сюда еще можно добавлять всякие нужные книги, прямо не связанные с С++, но думаю вы и сами на них натолкнетесь в процессе изучения. Так же всякие DirectX, OpenGL, базы данных и т.д и т.п. Что-то можно высмотреть еще тут: [хорошие книги по С++](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2006/09/c.html)

А еще, если вы windows ориентированный разработчик, лучше использовать для проектирования интерфейса GUI язык C#, а на С++ писать для него библиотеки. Но это уже потом.

**Удачи, если вы захотели стать профессионалом в области С++.**

**И помните про статью:** [Научитесь программировать за десять лет (Питер Норвиг)](http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html).

Comment: @Alex Krass, отличная подборка.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо. 

Если нахожу достойную литературу для чтения по разным направлениям, сохраняю для себя названия или ссылки. В ответ оставалось только разбить по порядку и категориям.

Comment: @Alex Krass Спасибо за ваш подробный и понятный ответ.

Comment: @Alex Krass, если в K&R, как Вы пишете, в каждом втором примере ошибка, то не покажете ли, нескоторые из них?  
(думаю, кроме использования `gets()` (если оно там осталось))

Comment: @avp, я исключительно пытаюсь уберечь психику тех, кому не повезет заполучить плохое издание. Слишком много выложенных в интернете версий похожи, а то и хуже, на эту(первая же ссылка в яндексе и гугле!): [lib.ru K&R](http://lib.ru/CTOTOR/kernigan.txt)

--------

Просто пройдитесь по примерам, я думаю Вы и сами все поймете. Все написано капсом, условия IF (C==' ' \\!\\! C=='\N'), ни слова про подключение заголовков, не указан тип возвращаемого main значения, старое определение функций с подписанными внизу переменными и т.д и т.п. Я просто не надеюсь на удачу и что повезет найти хорошее издание

Comment: @avp, я знаю, что это книга по своему хороша, хоть и не очень структурирована как по мне. Но слишком уж много плохих версий. Если хотите посоветовать кому-то K&R, то укажите хотя бы точное издание, год, издательский дом, или лучше ссылку с указанием брать только его и избегать других. Иначе это может стоит очень больших нервов изучающего.

Comment: @Alex Krass, видимо Вам попался [этот кошмар](http://chaos.ssu.runnet.ru/library/programms/progr/kr.pdf) . 

А вот [этот вариант(English)](http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf) или [этот на русском](http://people.toiit.sgu.ru/Sinelnikov/PT/C/Kern_Ritch.pdf) выглядят вполне пристойно.  
(правда, сходу увидел *gechar* вместо *getchar* в English (но исправлено в Russan!!!))

--

Конечно, последний раз я *внимательно читал* эту книгу лет 20 назад, так что с уверенностью рекомендовать какое-либо издание не возьмусь.

Comment: @Alex Krass Следующий вопрос прямо здесь. Язык C, как я помню, можно использовать для написания систем (но этим я заниматься не стану, ибо систем уже хватает), написания приложений на Windows. Можно ли на языке C писать программы под другие системы, например Linux, UNIX, Mac OS X и т.д.?

Comment: @smily_prg, запросто. 

Вообще-то большинство программ в этих системах написаны именно на Си.

А сам язык как раз и появился при разработке UNIX.  
(а Вы еще не читали эту историю?)

Answer (score 6):

Если опыта в программировании большого нет, то вместо С++ можно попробовать гораздо более простые "системные" языки с меньшим багажом, такие как [Go](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go), [Rust](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Если всё таки C++ необходим, то для адекватного изучения С++ придётся книгу ~1000 страниц изучать, например, [C++ Primer (издание, обновлённое для c++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242). Если опыт программирования уже есть, то рекомендуют "Accelerated C++".

Завершение небольших проектов -- хороший способов изучения новых языков: [1000+ Beginner Programming Projects](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2a9ygh/1000_beginner_programming_projects_xpost/).

[Научитесь программировать за десять лет (Питер Норвиг)](http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html).

Comment: @smily_prg, особое внимание обратите на "Научитесь программировать за десять лет"  
(совершенно серьезно, прочтите эту статью).

Comment: @jfs Большое спасибо. Уже посмотрел и очень доволен.

Comment: Go можно назвать системным языком наравне с Rust?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Как Go так и Rust называют системными языками.  Каждый из них использует концепции, с которыми стоит быть знакомыми (вне зависимости будете в них работать или нет). Языки достаточно различны, что практики из обоих языков полезно изучить.

Comment: @jfs наверное вопрос терминологии. Для меня Go с его непрямым управлением памятью (gc) не вписывается в понятие "системный".

Comment: @VladimirGamalian если вы думаете что "системный"  язык не может иметь gc, то вы ошибаетесь (прочтите хотя бы первый вопрос в Go FAQ: [цель проекта](https://golang.org/doc/faq#What_is_the_purpose_of_the_project)). Вне зависимости от того как слово "системный" определено, изучение Go полезно как в плане написания программ, которые раньше на C++ писались, так и в программировании на самом C++ позднее (например, чтобы знать какое подмножество языка  использовать можно эффективно).  Часть, связанная с ручным управлением памяти, ярко представлена в Rust. Не вижу оснований, чтобы минусовать ответ.

Comment: @jfs минус не мой ) То, что они в своем факе пишут, это больше реклама. Тоже самое они говорят про исключения - они тяжелые, и мы их не стали включать в язык. Я не против того, что полезно его изучить, меня только смутило позиционирование его как системного.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: они используют термин в [общепринятом значении](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming_language). Слово "системный" имеет полезные для заданного вопроса коннотации (поэтому я его использовал), но не стоит слишком серьёзно к отличию от "прикладных" языков относится--граница достаточно условна.

Answer (score 3):

Начните с Си. И обязательно в *nix (сейчас, очевидно Linux).

Для начала просто откройте K&R, читайте и пишите примеры.

Это даст Вам правильное понимание *основ*
(возможно потом (и с приобретением опыта реального программирования) желание использовать C++  уже пропадет, хотя изучать его все равно придется, поскольку слишком много кода все же написано на нем).

Comment: @avp Спасибо за ответ. Есть следующий вопрос, что такое K&R и почему обязательно начинать именно в Linux, чем не подойдет Windows?

Comment: [K&R](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%28%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%29) это книга от авторов языка Си. Можно легко найти в сети, можно купить бумажную версию в магазине.

С Linux надо начинать, хотя бы потому (не хочу углубляться в дебри систем), что в Windows разделителем в пути файла является символ `\`, который несет особое значение в строковых константах (то что Вы пишете в "abc") в C.

Ну, это досадная мелочь, на самом же деле речь о логичности системы.

Comment: @avp Скорее всего когда вы писали *nix вы могли иметь ввиду UNIX.

Comment: @smily_prg, именно так. 

Точнее \*nix это обозначение любой unix-подобной системы (в т.ч. Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX и десятков других).

Говорят, что для понимания их сути достаточно осознания принципов работы всего 5 системных функций -- open, read, write, fork и exec.

Answer (score 1):

Ответьте себе на вопросы: "Зачем мне C++?", "Что я хочу получить, используя его?". Поставьте интересную и нужную для Вас цель: игру, программу, что угодно, и идите к ней, учите инструментарий.

Что-то из Страуструпа можно почитать

Comment: Страуструп сложно, по-моему,  для начинающих, не так ли?

Comment: И да, и нет. Для меня Страуструп - своеобразный справочник: и начинающий сможет понять что и как, и профессионал не раз откроет какие-то мелочи распознать.

Comment: @b2soft дело в том, что мне нужны не все сразу с мелочами. Для начала мне хотелось бы изучить основу языка, но что можно назвать основой?

Comment: у страуструпа есть две книги - огромная, но обязательная, если серьезно в плюсы - собствено "язык программирования C++" и маленькая, облегченная "C++ primer", начинать можно со второй

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно начинаю все языки учить с видеороликов на YouTube. [Попробуйте](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=c%2B%2B+%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85) это, потом когда более-менее основу будете знать, переходите на книги, читайте Хабр, там очень много полезного есть, а потом всё будет изучаться по принципу снежного кома. Удачи :)

Comment: > начинаю все языки учить с видеороликов на YouTube.

И много языков выучили?

Comment: @Angus123 @Nofate Я конечно мог бы выучить что-нибудь на YouTube. Но дело в том, что если есть полный курс, то туда засунут много ненужного, а если, например, есть действительно хорошая серия туториалов - я не против, но проблема заключается в том, что хорошие полные курсы всегда платные. Поскольку C++ один из самых сложных языков программирования, то мне хотелось бы подойти к нему более серьезно.

Comment: @smily_prg, я ни в коем разе и не предлагаю учиться по "видеороликам".

Comment: @Nofate Я прислушаюсь к вашему совету.

Answer (score 0):

Мой одногруппник очень нахваливал Г.Шилдта. У него много разных учебников, в том числе и по С++

Comment: @Omfis Большое спасибо. Обязательно посмотрю.